# RabbitMQ messages shoing error : TypeError: queue.backing_queue_status is undefined ReferenceError: queue is not defined

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, rabbitmq, amqp

I am working on an java application which communicates with a RabbitMQ server. From yesterday some of the message queues started behaving strangely. I could see nothing is showing in the following fields for those weird queues:

Policy and State

And in fields "Ready","Unacked","Toatal" I could see "?". While clicking on the queues I could see the following error message :

TypeError: queue.backing_queue_status is undefined

ReferenceError: queue is not defined

The Biggest problem is that my application is fully dependent upon the RabbutMQ server. I have a separate thread running which fetches details from the queues and does some job. But the moment it tries to fetch the properties for those corrupted queues it looks like the thread suddenly dies. I could not see even an exception . The whole workflow stops.  Please help me out.

My Application specifications :

Language : Java

Framework : Spring 3.x

RabbitMQ version : 3.3.1

Framework Used to access RabbitMQ : spring-rabbit-1.2.1

Comment: Please, post more detail on queue setting, policies, etc.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that you have some issue on that machine where your RabbitMQ is located? E.g. not enough place on disk. Or a lot of open files (for sockets)

Comment: My main issue is with the thread that suddenly is  dying  and breaking the whole process. It is like an exception you can not catch. Is there any solution to not let the thread die and at least throw an exception so that I can handle at least?

Comment: I would suggest asking this question on the RabbitMQ mailing list